# Can't change hover color on button in Bootstrap/React Navbar

Tags: reactjs, navbar

new Developer here.

I'm having trouble changing the hover color on a button in my Navbar. I'm looking to add the styling direct to the line of code instead of bringing in custom css. Is there a way to do this ? What I have posted below is not working.

```
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        dispatch(connect());
                        getData();
                      }}
                    >
                      CONNECT
                    </Button>
```

Here is an example of styling that is working

```
          <s.Container flex={1} jc={"center"} ai={"center"}>
            <StyledImg alt={"example"} src={"###"} />
          </s.Container>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that the code didn't copy correctly. Sorry about that

```
          <Container>
            <Button variant="outline-secondary" className="navbarButton" style= {{hover: "#d00087"}}
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        dispatch(connect());
                        getData();
                      }}
                    >
                      CONNECT
                    </Button>
          </Container>
```